# Writing two functions which returns the first and last element of a list in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm pretty new to Haskell so I'm still getting the ropes of everything. I want to write two functions where the first one takes a list of Integers and returns the first element. The second function does the same but returns the last element. So far I have

```
firstList :: [Integer] -> Integer
firstList [] = 0
firstList (_:xs) = head xs

lastList :: [Integer] -> Integer
lastList [] = 0
lastList (_:xs) = (last) xs
```

The lastList function seems to be working but not firstList. For example, for the list [3, 1, 2, 4]; it returns 1 and not 3. How can I improve my code?

Comment: Your `firstList` returns the second item of the list. But I think the exercise is not to use `head` and `last` but to use pattern matching and recursion to obtin the first and last element.

Comment: `lastList [4]` will crash your program. That's because when you pattern match with `(_:xs)` you discard the first item (`_`) and call `last` with the tail `xs`, which can be empty. Similarly, in `firstList`, `head` is called with the tail of the original list, so it returns the second element (or crashes). So, don't discard the first element `_`. If this is an exercise, I think using `head` and `last` is cheating, since they make it much simpler.

Comment: read up on pattern-matching.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be mixing two possible approaches to this problem:

1. The no-effort approach

   ```
   firstList :: [Integer] -> Integer
   firstList = head
   ```

   ...or by β-expansion `firstList xs = head xs`. This simply invokes the standard `head` function without doing anything else. Which is certainly a way to solve the problem, but probably not what's expected in this task.
2. The all-manual approach

   ```
   firstList [] = ...
   firstList (x:xs) = ...
   ```

   In this setting, you're not calling anything from the libraries, but manually figuring out what to do with the head and tail (if any) of the list. Well, for `firstList` this is straightforward enough: you just *use* the head-element, i.e. `x`. Nothing more needs to be done, no further function to be called.

   OTOH, for `lastList` you'll actually need to do some more. Specifically, as chi commented, you don't actually handle the 1-element case, because you *always* strip away the head-element, if there's any. If that's the *only* element, then `last` doesn't get any to work with. What you should actually do there is not call a standard function at all, but instead handle all the relevant cases manually and the *recurse* with your own function.

   ```
   lastList [] = ...
   lastList [x] = ...
   lastList (_:xs) = lastList xs
   ```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand this question, you want the two function to return 0 when given an empty list and otherwiese the first or last element respectivly.

Haskell code:

```
firstList :: [Integer] -> Integer
firstList [] = 0
firstList (x:_) = x
```

In your code xs is the remaining portion of the list and thus head returns the second element of the original list